# Android library project to use in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, android-library

I have android source code(GB). I want to use an android library project in AOSP, in an apk. I read about defining the lib project into Android.mk, but I couldn't get a suitable ansewer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I think Remixing Android is the best article that can help you understand and write your own library. You can read it [here](http://marakana.com/s/post/1044/remixing_android).